# Captcha reload and sound buttons

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I'm having trouble using captcha for asp.net webpages.
Everything seems to work ok except that the reload and sound buttons are not located next to the captcha image as they should be. Instead they are underneath the textbox (image bellow)

[image: captcha_error]

Any help on how to solve this?

The code is:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li class="email">
            <label for="email" @if(!ModelState.IsValidField("email")){<text>class="error-label"</text>}>Email address</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="@email" @Validation.For("email") />
            @* Write any email validation errors to the page *@
            @Html.ValidationMessage("email")
        </li>
        <li class="password">
            <label for="password" @if(!ModelState.IsValidField("password")) {<text>class="error-label"</text>}>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" @Validation.For("password") />
            @* Write any password validation errors to the page *@
            @Html.ValidationMessage("password")
        </li>
        <li class="confirm-password">
            <label for="confirmPassword" @if(!ModelState.IsValidField("confirmPassword")) {<text>class="error-label"</text>}>Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" @Validation.For("confirmPassword") />
            @* Write any password validation errors to the page *@
            @Html.ValidationMessage("confirmPassword")
        </li>
        <li class="recaptcha">
                @Html.Label("Retype the code from the picture:", "CaptchaCode")
                <p></p>
                @{
                Captcha exampleCaptcha = new Captcha("ExampleCaptcha");
                exampleCaptcha.CodeLength = 4;
                exampleCaptcha.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 70);
                exampleCaptcha.UseHorizontalIcons = true; 
                exampleCaptcha.UserInputID = "CaptchaCode";
                exampleCaptcha.AdditionalCssClasses = "class1 class2 class3";
                }

                @Html.Raw(exampleCaptcha.Html)

                @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode")


       </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
```

Thanks,
Dinis

Comment: Where is your code. ?

Comment: Sorry, just posted the code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, problem solved!

I have forgotten to add the following line in the head section:

```
<link href="@BotDetect.Web.CaptchaUrls.Absolute.LayoutStyleSheetUrl" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```